# Retrying http request with .retryWhen return "retryWhen" does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to retry http request in angular when i get status 409 but when i put the `.retryWhen` after my http request i receive:

> Property 'retryWhen' does not exist on type 'Observable'.
>   [2339]

I try:

```
const requests = this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.map(p => {
    return this.marketplaceService.anunciar(p).pipe(take(1))

});

forkJoin(requests)

.retryWhen(error => {
    return error
        .flatMap((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 503) {
                return Observable.of(error.status).delay(1000)
            }
            return Observable.throw({
                error: 'No retry'
            });
        })
        .take(5)
        .concat(Observable.throw({
            error: 'Sorry, there was an error (after 5 retries)'
        }));
})

    .subscribe(resultAnuncios => {

                console.log(resultAnuncios);

}
```

I import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
```

My service:

```
anunciar(produtosConfirmados: any):Observable<any>{


    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'anuncio/anunciar', {
        sku: xxx.,
        }
    })
```

Comment: you may want to try `.pipe(retryWhen...)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this? Im having similar issues trying to have a retryWhen inside of a forkjoin. I was trying to loop over calls until each call returned a specific status in their response data. Any calls that came back with a 'pending' status in their response would just be retried.